# INDEX VIEW by total lines

Tags: sql, view

Good Day

How can I add a Column to a view to show the number of lines? 1,2,3,4 etc. I need this in a view and not a Table.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the definition of the view and the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeName) AS Row, 
    EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Salary 
FROM Employees
```

output

```
Row   EmployeeId   EmployeeName     Salary
-------------------------------------------
1     1002         Alden            4000
2     2343         Lawson           4500
3     2004         Barbra           4800
```

you can do that in view.

Comment: if that helped, it would be nice if you accept it as an answer.